# Text number to existing list elements using javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, append

I wanted to text numbers to existing list elemensts. for example:

I have the elements like this. I have created diffrent list item in to my application. But I have text numbers orderly in to it.

```
<div class="section-01">
    <ul class="numbers-wrap">
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="numbers-wrap">
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="numbers-wrap">
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="section-02">
    <ul class="numbers-wrap">
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="numbers-wrap">
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="numbers-wrap">
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    <li class="numbers-li"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I wanted to add numbers to all list (.numbers-li) orderly like this:

Result should be like this

```
<div class="section-01">
        <ul class="numbers-wrap">
        <li class="numbers-li">1</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">2</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">3</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="numbers-wrap">
        <li class="numbers-li">4</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">5</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="numbers-wrap">
        <li class="numbers-li">6</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">7</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">8</li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="section-02">
        <ul class="numbers-wrap">
        <li class="numbers-li">9</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">10</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">11</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">12</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="numbers-wrap">
        <li class="numbers-li">13</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">14</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">15</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="numbers-wrap">
        <li class="numbers-li">16</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">17</li>
        <li class="numbers-li">18</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Also please let me know how to text only odd numbers into it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.numbers-li').each(function(index){
    $(this).text(parseInt(index,10) + 1);
})
```

Update (for odd numbers. can be used to print even numbers by changing oddum = 2)

```
var oddnum = 1;
$('.numbers-li').each(function(index){
    $(this).text(oddnum);
    oddnum = oddnum + 2;
})
```

Comment: Hi Cerlin Thanks alot. Also can we add only odd number in to it

Comment: if this helped you then you should accept the answer(according to stackoverflow rules).

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').each(function(index){
        $(this).text(parseInt(index,10)+ 1);
    })
});
```

note: here `$(this).text(parseInt(index)+ 1)` also can be used, but you should always use `base value` when you are using `parseInt` otherwise it may lead you to some undesired results.